# Several (multi) functions of the controller AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, function, scope, controller

I want to use several functions in one controller. First family makes a request, the second part of the page should display by pressing the button (as here http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_events_toggle).
The first function is working fine, but the second is not.

`app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($http) {},function($scope){})`

This is the second function of the controller:

```
    function($scope){
  $scope.showMe=false;
 $scope.myFunc=function() {
     $scope.showMe=!$scope.showMe;
 }
```

As planned at the touch of a button should show the page:
``

```
<body ng-app="jsbin">
  <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as vm">
   <button ng-click="myFunc()">Click Me!</button>
     <div ng-show=vm.showMe>
         <h1>Menu:</h1>
         <div>Pizza</div>
         <div>Pasta</div>
         <div>Pesce</div>
     </div>
       </div>
```

`
Sourse:http://zalil.su/3296697

Answer (score 0, accepted):

angular controller takes one function with all dependencies.
    app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($http,$scope) {
     $scope.showMe=false;

```
 $scope.myFunc=function() {
 $scope.showMe=!$scope.showMe;
 }

 $scope.makeAjax= function(){
    $http.something()...
 }
```

})

got through this link https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller